# PHP get data from MySQL by clicking on Href link and showing results in the same url

Tags: php, html

i'm faced with a situation where i want to click on a link and get data based on the $id. I'm able to do this but my problem is that i want the results to show on the same page not redirect to another page

```html
$con = dbConnect();
 $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT manuscript_id,authors,month,year,title,journal,pubmed_link FROM manuscript WHERE title like '%$term%'");
  $sql->execute();
  $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//
  if ($sql->fetch() == 0){
  echo ('<h2>SORRY! No results found</h2>');
   }


  else {
  
  $x=1;  
  while ($row = $sql->fetch()){//three
    $manuscript_id = $row ['manuscript_id'];
    $author = $row ['authors'];
    $month = $row ['month'];
    $year = $row ['year'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $journal = $row ['journal'];
    $pubmed_link = $row ['pubmed_link'];
  
  
  echo $x++;
  echo "<input type = 'checkbox' id='list' value='list'>";
  echo ('<a href="abstract.php?manuscript_id=' . $manuscript_id . '">' . $title . '</a>') . "</br>" . "\r\n" . $author . "</br>" . "\r\n" . "<u>" . $journal . "</u>" . "&nbsp" . $month . "\r\n" . "&nbsp" . $year . "\r\n" . "</br>" . "</br>";


  }
```

Is there a way i can avoid redirecting to "abstract.php"?

Comment: thanks Fred but seeking a php/html solution as introduction of Ajax might mean rewritting the whole module

Comment: Someone posted an answer for you. I can't see how this can be done without JS/Ajax, other than an iframe.

Comment: Point it to an `<iframe>` - HTML solution.

Comment: Thanks for this reminder Fred...i'm a green horn on Stackoverflow but not an excuse for my ignorance. Will make a point to tick green

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript & jQuery for that.

```
<a href="abstract.php?manuscript_id=' . $manuscript_id . '" class="clickMe">
<div id="results"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.clickMe').click(function(e){
   // Stop default click action in browser
   e.preventDefault();

   // Make ajax call
   $.ajax($(e.target).attr("href"), {
     cache:false,
     success:function(data){
         $("#results").html(data);
     }
   });
})
</script>
```

That will do the trick. :)

Comment: OP: *"thanks Fred but seeking a php/html solution as introduction of Ajax might mean rewritting the whole module –  Maina 4 mins ago"* - `$.ajax` is still "Ajax".

Comment: This is the only way, also you could use json to transfer your data. That will cost you less bytes, so it will be faster. ;)

Comment: Thanks Marko..but still

Comment: There sure must be a PHP/Html solution

Comment: You could try iframe?

Comment: ^ Which is what I said; twice ;-) 1st; 16 mins. ago. *"other than an iframe."*

Comment: Not a problem Marko. OP has enough information to come up with a solution. But, given the OP's track record, am afraid that my putting in an answer may not yield a "green tick" ;-) we can only suggest. *Cheers*

Comment: i think you have misunderstood me.What i'm trying to do is to avoid using "abstract.php" as the page i am taken to when i click on the link . i found something similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174282/link-to-reload-current-page  but cannot view results. i get a Apache error 403 forbiden