# How to remove query string from URL using href

Tags: html, url

Currently, my page URL looks something like so:

```
https://example.com/eg?page=2
```

The URL can also sometimes look like:

```
https://example.com/eg/?page=2
```

I want to redirect the user to the same page, but without the query string, so that when clicking on a link it will take you to:

```
https://example.com/eg
```

I tried using the following `href` in an anchor tag suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174282/link-to-reload-current-page) question:

```
<a href=".">To home</a>
```

When clicking on the link, it removes the query string like I want when the current page URL is `https://example.com/eg/?page=2`. However, if the page URL is `https://example.com/eg?page=2` it takes me to `https://example.com`.

**Question:** Is there some type of directory path (ie url I can use in my href) I can use such that the two above URLs will always remove the query string? I can use javascript, but if a solution without is possible that would be preferred.

***Note:*** I cannot hard code `eg` into my `href` url as I'm developing a widget which can sit in different environments, so, `eg` is subject to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A relative link beginning with `?` should only modify the query string, so you could use:

```
<a href="?">Home</a>
```

Which would direct your example URLs to:

```
https://example.com/eg?
https://example.com/eg/?
```

It does include the `?` in the final URL, which might not be what you want, but it is a functional option if you don't want to use Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You can use,

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href.split('?')[0];">Home</a>
```

You can also use `document.location` instead of `window.location`. But it is not recommended. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430948/3091398)

Answer (score 2):

Apply this script into your `a` tag.

```
<a href="javascript:document.location.href=document.location.href.split('?')[0];">Home</a>
```

Comment: I guess this removes hash after query string which might not be desired.